# Least Square Conformal Map Charts growing

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, textures

I'm trying to implement the [LSCM](http://alice.loria.fr/index.php/publications.html?Paper=lscm@2002) algorithm for texture unwrap. So far I've done detecting and growing features, as you can see on the screenshots:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

As for the algorithm itself, as it is described in ALICE, now I should create (or "grow") charts using these seams. ALICE's LSCM uses some nifty terminology I can't understand (my maths knowledge is really poor). The thing I can not understand is what is a *facet* and how I can find the distance from my *half-edge* to the *facet*.

My code is published [on Github](https://github.com/shybovycha/irrPaint3D).

**The question is:** how to split the mesh into charts using the seams generated by the first step of an algorithm?

Comment: As a swede I have to say I think that viking is quite stereotype. I'm not saying it's racist, but very stereotype.

Comment: If the seams are generated correctly, then each seam should connect two parts of the mesh together. You can begin with creating facets by connecting triangles that share an edge that does not belong to any seam. After that, only the seam edges are left, along with a set of discontinuous groups of facets, so you can create a graph that connects pairs of facet groups that are connected by a seam edge. Should be easy ...

Comment: Were you able to complete LSCM implementation in your code IrrPaint3D? I am looking for a cpp example code as reference to implement something similar. Please let me know the status of your project.

Comment: @codetiger the project was left behind long time ago now; probably I won't  continue working on it in the nearest future. The link to the project is mentioned in the question: https://github.com/shybovycha/irrPaint3D

Comment: @shybovycha Yes, I saw your code, but before I start following the code, I just wanted to make sure if it was in completed state.

Comment: @codetiger no, I was trying to implement LSCM algorithm and failed. Yet, that was far too long ago, thus I think my chances to implement it from scratch are higher now. So, stay tuned ;) You've just put a hope into my mind =)

Comment: If you want someone to collaborate in this, let me know. I am open to work together on this. However, I am trying to add LSCM into Assimp project. https://github.com/assimp/assimp